# p4vs plug is not showing in VS2017 15.3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2017, perforce

Any work arounds to use p4v (perforce plugin) under source control?

I've VS 2012,2015 & 2017 side by side.

with the previous version (<15.3) there was no issue, since the update installed the plug in gone missing.

did tried multiple uninstall and re-install using extension.

Also tried including the VS2017 group in Vsix amnifest,no luck.

Comment: Are other plug-ins missing, too?

Comment: @bahrep no there are the ones which are shipped with the product TFS,Git are working but the ones explicit install are not. Seems like the problem is lying within visual studio. DId tried with Visual svn, Ankh svn.Also did tried with TODO manager which is not showing either.( under other windows)

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119486/on-fresh-installation-extensions-are-not-working.html opened a support request with VS team

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/119886/view.html does this workaround work for you?

Comment: that was me posted there. to be honest I didn't fix anything but it started working - as per the solution posted I have restarted post update and noticed the extensions were carried along.

Answer (score 1):

Because I was in badly need to update VS, I did tried again but this time

> I have installed 15.0 first and then installed the extensions,
>   following Update to 15.3.5 and restarted the computer without
>   launching the VS immediately

.

Everything seems to be working.

Also tried installing a new extension which seems to be working.

> Perhaps VS rolled out a fix overnight and included in the
>   update.(15.3.5)..